# R jsonlite does not parse JSON as per keys correctly

Tags: r, json, data.table, jsonlite

When converting json to columns in R using jsonlite, I came across a bug where the column values were in the wrong columns. I tried replicating it -

```
R> dt <- data.table(id = 1:2, 
json = c('{"user": "xyz2", "weightmap": "w1", "domains": "d1"}', 
         '{"weightmap": "w2", "user": "abcd", "domains": "d2"}'))                                                                                                                                                                       

R> dt[,fromJSON(json),.(id)]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   id user weightmap domains
1:  1 xyz2        w1      d1
2:  2   w2      abcd      d2
```

From what I understand, jsonlite picks the keys from the first row and expects the json in all rows to be in the same order.

I also tried this with different datatypes. Eg. If `weightmap` was a complex datastructure like a list or another nested json, it would fail saying the columns types are not consistent.

Is this expected behavior ? Should'nt it always read from the keys and split to cols ?

Is there a way to make jsonlite parse the json correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this is a "bug" in `data.table`, where it is internally treating each as a `list` instead of a `data.frame` with names that need to be aligned. We can force it this way:

```r
dt[, c(.SD, rbindlist(lapply(json, jsonlite::fromJSON), use.names=TRUE))][, json := NULL][]
#       id   user weightmap domains
#    <int> <char>    <char>  <char>
# 1:     1   xyz2        w1      d1
# 2:     2   abcd        w2      d2
```

If there is any complexity, what happens depends on the structure. For example, if a `weightmap` is a list, then

```r
dt <- data.table(id = 1:2, 
    json = c('{"user": "xyz2", "weightmap": ["w1","w2"], "domains": "d1"}', 
             '{"weightmap": "w2", "user": "abcd", "domains": "d2"}'))
dt[, c(.SD, rbindlist(lapply(json, jsonlite::fromJSON), use.names=TRUE))][, json := NULL][]
# Warning in as.data.table.list(jval, .named = NULL) :
#   Item 1 has 2 rows but longest item has 3; recycled with remainder.
# Warning in as.data.table.list(jval, .named = NULL) :
#   Item 2 has 2 rows but longest item has 3; recycled with remainder.
#       id   user weightmap domains
#    <int> <char>    <char>  <char>
# 1:     1   xyz2        w1      d1
# 2:     2   xyz2        w2      d1
# 3:     1   abcd        w2      d2
```

which achieves an "unnesting" (noisily).

Comment: yeah, figured out it was the implicit rbindlist that was causing the problem. We solved it in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt[,':='(jsonb=list(as.data.table(fromJSON(json)))),.(id)]
dt[,setcolorder(jsonb[[1]], sort(names(jsonb[[1]]))),.(id)]
```

The issue was that data table uses an implicit rbindlist over the lists generated for the groups. rbindlist always binds as per position unless `use.names` is given.

We resolved this issue by setting the colorder explicitly from the first json row so that the order of json fields are maintained.